# Storing a dynamic array of structs which contains a dynamic array of structs

Tags: solidity, arrays, struct

I am trying to create the following objects:

```
Bounty[] public bounties;

struct Bounty {
    address issuer;
    uint256 fulfillmentAmount;
    uint256 balance;
    bool bountyOpen;
    Fulfillment[] fulfillments;
    mapping (bytes32 => bool) used;
}

struct Fulfillment {
    uint256 fulfillmentAmount;
    address fulfiller;
}
```

A brief explanation is that I want to have an array of "Bounties" which can be satisfied multiple times. Each bounty has a number of properties, one of which is an array of "Fulfillments". The fulfillments describe and store the different times the bounty was fulfilled.

When trying to create a new bounty, I use the following:

```
bounties.push(Bounty(msg.sender, _fulfillmentAmount, msg.value, true));
```

This gives me the error that I have one fewer parameters than needed to initialize the object, because I am missing the `Fulfillment[]` array. (I do not need the mapping to be initialized.)

When I try to initialize with the array object like so:

```
bounties.push(Bounty(msg.sender, _fulfillmentAmount, msg.value, true, new Fullfillment[](0)));
```

I get the following error:

> UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct ContractName.Fulfillment memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.

I have looked at a number of similar questions: [[1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12611/solidity-filling-a-struct-array-containing-itself-an-array)] [[2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30857/how-to-initialize-an-empty-array-inside-a-struct)] [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345903/copying-of-type-struct-memory-memory-to-storage-not-yet-supported)]

They seem to imply that creating an object like this is not supported.
Instead, I could turn `Fullfillment[] fulfillments` into:

```
uint fulfillmentLength;
mapping(uint => Fullfilment) fullfillments;
```

Keeping track of the length myself and doing some tricks to replace `push()`.

Is this the best practice here? Or should I look at other alternatives like having the `fulfillments` be an object outside of the `Bounty`.

This is what `Bounties-Network/StandardBounties` seems to do:

https://github.com/Bounties-Network/StandardBounties/blob/master/contracts/StandardBounties.sol

Looking for best practice advice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked a lot better using a mapping to store the struct.

I used user-supplied keys for random access to the mapped structs and added a list of the keys in case iteration is important.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract Bounties {

    // an unordered list of keys

    bytes32[] public bountyList;

    struct Bounty {
        bool isBounty; // simple collision check
        address issuer;
        uint256 fulfillmentAmount;
        uint256 balance;
        bool bountyOpen;
        Fulfillment[] fulfillments;
        mapping (bytes32 => bool) used;
    }

    struct Fulfillment {
        uint256 fulfillmentAmount;
        address fulfiller;
    }

    // a mapping to the Bounty structs
    mapping(bytes32 => Bounty) public bountyStructs;

    function isBounty(bytes32 key) public view returns(bool isIndeed) {
        return bountyStructs[key].isBounty;
    }

    function newBounty(bytes32 key, address _issuer, uint amount) public payable returns(bool success) {
        require(!isBounty(key)); // no duplicates
        bountyList.push(key);
        bountyStructs[key].isBounty = true;
        bountyStructs[key].issuer = _issuer;
        bountyStructs[key].fulfillmentAmount = amount;
        bountyStructs[key].balance = msg.value;
        bountyStructs[key].bountyOpen = true;
        // no need to initialize the mapping
        // should emit an event here
        return true;
    }

    function appendFulfillment(bytes32 bountyKey) public payable returns(bool success) {
        require(isBounty(bountyKey));
        Fulfillment memory f;
        f.fulfillmentAmount = msg.value;
        f.fulfiller = msg.sender;
        bountyStructs[bountyKey].fulfillments.push(f);
        // should emit an event here.
        return true;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This makes sense. Two questions. First, is my original structure proposal not possible in Solidity today? As in there is no syntax error, it just won't work. Second, is there a benefit to your design vs [StandardBounty.sol](https://github.com/Bounties-Network/StandardBounties/blob/master/contracts/StandardBounties.sol), or is it mostly just preference at that point?

Comment: Without looking too deeply into it, I imagine the original issue is a limitation of the interface design. That's why I tried to stay with the nesting - to show it's not inherently wrong. Both structures seem reasonable enough. I don't see an obvious way to enumerate fulfillments by bounty in their structure. Although I didn't write the getter function, your way inclines in that direction, if that's what you're hoping for. Thanks for accepting the answer. ;-)